# Identity Server 4 Running Behind a load Balancer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have setup Identity Server 4 for my project using Entity Framework. I already configured the service to use a persisted grant Store and a Signed Certificate.

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddSigningCredential(Config.GetSigningCertificate())
        .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>()
        .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
        .AddConfigurationStore(builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
                        options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
        .AddOperationalStore(builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
                        options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
```

Here is the configuration of the service.

The problem is when I run my server behind a load balancer with for exemple 2 identic instances handling all the request, the server where the user did not logged in fail to decode the JWT token, leading to 401 unauthorized errors.

I'm assuming the sigining method of the tokens or their encription is the problem but I cannot find a way to solve this.

Here is the rest of my configuration.

The Configure:

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
      Authority = url,
      // Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
      AllowedScopes = { "WebAPI" },
      RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
      AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
      AutomaticChallenge = true,

});
```

the Client:

```
new Client
{
     ClientId = "Angular2SPA",
     AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword, // Resource Owner Password Credential grant.
     AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
     RequireClientSecret = false, // This client does not need a secret to request tokens from the token endpoint.
     AccessTokenLifetime = 7200, // Lifetime of access token in seconds.
     AllowedScopes = {
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId, // For UserInfo endpoint.
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                       "roles",
                       "WebAPI"
                      },
     AllowOfflineAccess = true, // For refresh token.
     AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt

}
```

I also implemented my own IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator and IProfileService.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: In the olden days you'd have to make sure all machines in the web garden (omg am so old) would have to have the same machine key or some such. Probably a similar problem here.  Don't know what they're using for encryption, but whatever it is it has to be the same on all the identity server machines.

Comment: The thing is         `.AddSigningCredential(Config.GetSigningCertificate())`
get a certificate from my storage and it's the same on every machine. So it's able to decrypt the refresh_tokens stored in db, but odly not the JWT tokens.

Comment: Seems like that's not what's responsible for signing the JWT tokens.  The question is, exactly what is?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking the same, but I cannot find a way to modify the cert or key used to encrypt or sign the tokens. :/ Any idea where this is set?

Comment: I'd start reading through the code https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer Looks like you can sneak into JwtBearerOptions and control how they are validated via ISecurityTokenValidator (SecurityTokenValidators property).  This blog has a lot of info to, it appears https://andrewlock.net/a-look-behind-the-jwt-bearer-authentication-middleware-in-asp-net-core/ I've never done any of this stuff with Core, so I'm not much more of a help.  Good luck!

Comment: Well thanks, I'll try to get into the security token validator.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, load balancing Identity Server 4 and was able to share the keys using .AddDataProtection() in ConfigureServices of Startup.cs .

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
// Other service configurations

  services.AddDataProtection();

// Additional service configurations    
}
```

As a side note, if you go this route, consider encrypting those keys (in whichever medium you decide to use) using an extension like
`.ProtectKeysWith*` (there are several options)
. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.1 for further information

HTH